# How to append text in end of document and apply style to it

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to append a heading and paragraph into an existing google docs document, I'm able to insert text at the end of document using:

```
{
  'insertText': {
      'endOfSegmentLocation': {},
      'text': '\n' + HEADING + '\n'
  }
}
```

But when we want to apply styling with insert text we need a start_index and end_index, the problem is I don't have start_index for this as I'm appending it to the end of document.

Complete code:

```
requests = [
            {
                'insertText': {
                    'endOfSegmentLocation': {},
                    'text': '\n' + HEADING + '\n'
                }
            },
        {
            'updateParagraphStyle': {
                'range': {
                    'startIndex': HOW TO FIND START INDEX?,
                    'endIndex':  len(HEADING)
                },
                'paragraphStyle': {
                    'namedStyleType': 'HEADING_1',
                    'spaceAbove': {
                        'magnitude': 10.0,
                        'unit': 'PT'
                    },
                    'spaceBelow': {
                        'magnitude': 10.0,
                        'unit': 'PT'
                    }
                },
                'fields': 'namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow'
            }
        },
        {
            'insertText': {
                'endOfSegmentLocation': {},
                'text': PARAGRAPHS + '\n'
            }
        },
    ]

    
    result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
        documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current stage, unfortunately, the property of `range` has no `endOfSegmentLocation` and both `startIndex` and `endIndex` are required to be used. So, in this case, first, the last index is required to be retrieved. When this is reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
res1 = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute() # Here, last index is retrieved.
startIndex = res1["body"]["content"][-1]["endIndex"]
requests = [
    {"insertText": {"endOfSegmentLocation": {}, "text": "\n" + HEADING + "\n"}},
    {
        "updateParagraphStyle": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": startIndex,
                "endIndex": startIndex + len(HEADING),
            },
            "paragraphStyle": {
                "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1",
                "spaceAbove": {"magnitude": 10.0, "unit": "PT"},
                "spaceBelow": {"magnitude": 10.0, "unit": "PT"},
            },
            "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow",
        }
    },
    {"insertText": {"endOfSegmentLocation": {}, "text": PARAGRAPHS + "\n"}},
]
result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={"requests": requests}).execute()
```

#### References:

- [Range](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#range)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

Comment: Coming here late, I used same approach, it works for me!

Comment: @WatchMyApps Lab Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.